# Calling multiple arguments in an array from a function [PHP]

Tags: php, class

I am trying to call multiple arguments from a function in php using an array.

```
Class useful {
    function callFunctionFromClass($className, $function, $args = array()) {
            return $className::$function($args);
     }
}

<?php
    require("library/class.php");

    $u = new useful;

    $u::callFunctionFromClass(new useful, "text", "Test", "Test");
?>
```

I have the function text() created aswell like so:

```
function text($msg, $msg2) {
    echo $msg;
    echo $msg2;
}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Warning: Missing argument 2 for useful::text(), 
  called in htdocs\class\library\class.php on line 16 
  and defined in htdocs\class\library\class.php on line 11
Test
Notice: Undefined variable: msg2 in htdocs\class\library\class.php on line 13
```

This works fine without $msg2 & a second argument. So how is multiple         arguments pulled off?

Comment: You are calling a non-static class as a static class `$u::callFunctionFromClass(new useful, "text", "Test", "Test");` that should be reporting an error also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.call-user-func-array.php). Also you are calling `callFunctionFromClass` as a static method but it isn't static

```
Class useful
{
    public function callFunctionFromClass($className, $function, $args = array())
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($className, $function), $args);
    }

    public function text($msg, $msg2)
    {
        echo $msg;
        echo $msg2;
    }
}

$u = new useful;

$test = $u->callFunctionFromClass('useful', "text", array("Test", "Test"));
```

Comment: Fixed it, just got rid of var_dump() and used it like I was earlier, Thanks!

Comment: that's because the method `text` is not returning anything.. you must use `return` inside the `text` method in order to have something returned